# JNI %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, 64-bit, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm running Netbeans on 64-bit Windows 8, with JDK 1.7_25 (64-bit), following the instructions for the Beginning JNI with NetBeans (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html)

The instructions are for linux, but the principle is the same for Windows I believe (generating a .dll file instead of .so, using win32 includes in the JDK, etc)

I have Cygwin64 installed as well as Cygwin32. Using Cygwin64, I'm able to generate a 64-bit DLL from my C/C++ Dynamic Library project. However, when I call System.load("path/to/JNITest.dll"), I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNITestLib\dist\JNITest.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
    at jnitest.JNITest.main(JNITest.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

From what I gather, this is most often the case when loading a 64-bit application on a 32-bit virtual machine, but my netbeans.conf is pointing to a 64-bit JVM.

Additionally, when I use the 32-bit version of Cygwin to compile things and run, I get

```
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

I'm pretty sure I'm correctly generating the DLL file, it's just a simple HelloWorld printf to follow the JNI tutorial. I'm very new to JNI and C, so I'm not really sure where to start debugging. The best I've done is tried both 32 and 64-bit DLLs, and I've made sure my C compiler (Cygwin) is 64-bit, and my JVM is too.

I'd appreciate any insight!

Edit: Here are the included files

=== Java (JNITest.java) ===

```
package jnitest;

public class JNITest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("JVM: " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        System.load("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JNITestLib\\dist\\JNITest.dll");

        new JNITest().doHello();
    }

    public native void doHello();
}
```

=== Generated javah header (jnitest_JNITest.h) ===

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jnitest_JNITest */

#ifndef _Included_jnitest_JNITest
#define _Included_jnitest_JNITest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jnitest_JNITest
 * Method:    doHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnitest_JNITest_doHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

=== C (JNITest.c) ===

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "jnitest_JNITest.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnidemojava_Main_nativePrint
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) 
{
    printf("\nHello World from C\n");

}
```

Edit:

The problem seems to be with the DLL, since I can load other 64-bit DLLs just fine. I thought that Cygwin might be the problem, so I changed my compiler to MinGW-w64. It compiled fine, and the library loads, but now I get a new exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnitest.JNITest.doHello()V
    at jnitest.JNITest.doHello(Native Method)
    at jnitest.JNITest.main(JNITest.java:10)
Java Result: 1
```

Some more digging found that the error is thrown when ClassLoader reads libs.size() here:

```
// Invoked in the VM class linking code.
    static long findNative(ClassLoader loader, String name) {
        Vector<NativeLibrary> libs =
            loader != null ? loader.nativeLibraries : systemNativeLibraries;
        synchronized (libs) {
            int size = libs.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                NativeLibrary lib = libs.elementAt(i);
                long entry = lib.find(name);
                if (entry != 0)
                    return entry;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Edit: ANSWERS!

Finally figured it out.

Firstly, something was wrong with Cygwin64. Using a different 64-bit C compiler got rid of the not a valid win32 application error.

Secondly, my JNITest.c file's method signature was incorrect. It should have been:

```
Java_jnitest_JNITest_doHello
```

Instead of

```
Java_jnitest_Main_doHello
```

After changing that, it works!

(though I can't answer my own question for another 6 hours... so dum de dum)

Comment: Find a 64 bit dll that you did not create yourself. Does that work? If so, your dll is invalid for some reason which we can discuss later.

Comment: Yes, I added System.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\aaclient.dll"), random 64-bit dll, before the System.load of my dll and that worked. I still got an exception when I tried to load mine though. I honestly do not know anything about dlls, so I'm not sure where to start on why it's invalid

Comment: I can't help you there, because I don't know either, but now it appears to no longer be a Java problem and instead a C/C++/Win32API/DLL issue.

Comment: So thinking it might be the 64-bit Cygwin compiler, I downloaded MinGW64 and used it to compile the dll. This time, the library loads, but I'm getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnitest.JNITest.doHello()V

Comment: That seems like it's a header issue. Did you look at your method declarations and definition? They confuse the hell out of me.

Comment: As far as I know `.exe` and `.dll` cygwin executables are not actually windows executables as they depend on `cygwin1.dll` to communicate to windows. MinGW, I think, generates windows native executables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

Firstly, something was wrong with Cygwin64. Using a different 64-bit C compiler got rid of the not a valid win32 application error.

Secondly, my JNITest.c file's method signature was incorrect. It should have been:

```
Java_jnitest_JNITest_doHello
```

Instead of

```
Java_jnitest_Main_doHello
```

After changing that, it works!

Comment: Any ideas what was specifically wrong with the cygwin compiler?